# Access hidden field in external javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I have an aspx page contining a hiddenfield

`<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnObjectID" runat="server" />`

I want to get the value of hiddenfield in external javascript file.
I have used this code to get the value of hdnObjectID

```
var objectID = parseInt($('#' + '<%= hdnObjectID.ClientID %>')[0].value);
```

But its not getting the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your Javascript:
var objectID = parseInt(document.getElementById('hdnObjectID').value);

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to access server variable if its written in external JS file. I have explained this reason in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711425/is-there-is-any-appropriate-solution-to-clear-server-side-session-on-client-side/11711578#comment15558088_11711578)

In your aspx page, declare a global javascript variable

```
var hdnTextBox = <%= hdnObjectID.ClientID %>;
```

use this variable in your external file.

If you are using asp.net 4.0, you can then control the client id of the control. For how to control it, see [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18225/Controlling-our-ClientIDs-in-ASPNET-4.htm)

The other option would be to write the JS from server side with the help ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. Write the following code in your page_load

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "SomeName","SomeFunc("          +hdnObjectID.ClientID + ");", true);
```

and in your external file

```
function SomeFunc(hdnObjectClientId){
 //
}
```

and pass in the client id to the function

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<%= hdnObjectID.ClientID %>` in an external js file because these server side expressions doesn't evalute in an extrnal js file.

You can create a function in your page to get value from that hidden field though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate server code in a JavaScript file.

If you use [static client IDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx), you can safely hardcode the value in your external file. Otherwise, pass it as an argument to your JavaScript method from the page.

```
// in file
function foo(clientId){
    var element = document.getElementById(clientId);
}
```

---

```
<%-- in page markup -->
<script>
    foo("<%=hdnObjectId.ClientID %>");
</script>


// or, register in codebehind in OnPreRender (or where suitable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
In your external javascript

```
var Controls = null; 
function readHidden(){alert(Controls.hdn_val.value);}
```

---

In .aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myexternal.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
Controls = {hdnfld = '<%=hdn_val.ClientID %>'};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass "hdnObjectID" in findElement javascript method to get the object

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function findElement(e) {
        var foundElement = null;

        var elements = window.document.forms[0].elements;

        for (i = 0 ; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].id.indexOf(e) > -1) {
                foundElement = elements[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return foundElement;
    }
 </script>
```

This method will return the object with mayching name. But if there are two objects with similar names than this method will require modifictaions

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Assign", "assignValues('"+ hdnSchedule.Value +"');", true);
```